# How to unveil typedef in C/C++ sources?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, typedef, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to parse C/C++-code with my primitive parser to get ast-tree.

But it doesn't support macro and typedefs.

It is possible to unveil macro definitions in any C/C++-project with help of gcc options. 
After that my own parser is able to cope with C/C++-code, but only in case, if there is no typedefs in it.

So, I'd like in some way to get rid of typedefs. But I have no idea, what should I do.

I want to replace redefined type names, for example:

```
typedef char CHAR;
typedef int& INT;
INT a;
CHAR b;
```

by their originals:

```
int &a;
char b;
```

As result, I want to get the same sources, but with original types, without typedefs.

I guess, it is very simple task for compiler, but not for the student's project. :)

As far, as I know, DECL_ORIGINAL_TYPE (TYPE_NAME (t)) of g++ points to the tree node with original object's type. 
But I really wouldn't like to dive into the g++ sources to adopt it for my demands.

So, what is the easiest way to unveil the typedefs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited:**

The solution with GCCXML is really good, but I still don't understand, how to get 
C/C++ code from it's XML representation. Could you explain, what should I do to transform XML:

```
(an example from http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/example1out.html)

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GCC_XML>
  <Namespace id="_1" name="::" members="_2 _3 _4 "/>
  <Function id="_2" name="main" returns="_5" context="_1" location="f0:8"/>
  <Function id="_3" name="a_function" returns="_5" context="_1" location="f0:4">
    <Argument name="f" type="_6"/>
    <Argument name="e" type="_4"/>
  </Function>
  <Struct id="_4" name="EmptyClass" context="_1" location="f0:1" members="_7 _8 " bases=""/>
  <FundamentalType id="_5" name="int"/>
  <FundamentalType id="_6" name="float"/>
  <Constructor id="_7" name="EmptyClass" context="_4" location="f0:1">
    <Argument name="_ctor_arg" type="_9"/>
  </Constructor>
  <Constructor id="_8" name="EmptyClass" context="_4" location="f0:1"/>
  <ReferenceType id="_9" type="_4c"/>
  <File id="f0" name="example1.cxx"/>
</GCC_XML>
```

back to C/C++:

```
(an example from http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/example1in.html)

struct EmptyClass {};

int a_function(float f, EmptyClass e)
{
}

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Could you explain it please?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option for `g++` (and by the way, do you handle templates? If you do, typedefs should be a piece of cake in comparison, and if you don't, it's not `c++` yet :)

Comment: Unless you put some serious constraints upon your requirements, this task amounts to implementing a large portion of a C++ compiler frontend.

Comment: Why not use clang for the task?

Comment: have you looked at GCC-MELT: http://gcc-melt.org/ ?

Comment: Anton Kovalenko 
No, templates will be implemented in a a bright future. :)
But at this moment, I need to unveal the typedefs.

Comment: Alexey Frunze, 
Does clang compiler have necessary command line option? Do you mean to look at clang's Framework?

Comment: Necrolis, 
Is it possible to replace the redefined type of C/C++ with initial type in with help of GCC-MELT extension? Could you explain, what should I do?

Comment: You've asked a second question, "how can I generate C++ from XML".  SO suggests you start a second question.  As it is here, you're unlikely to get any kind of response, as it appears to be part of your first question.     Regarding your second question: you said you wanted to *parse* C++; what has regenerating C++ from GCCXML got to do with your need to parse C++?

Comment: The answer of Mr. CapelliC fits my demands. It was accepted. I have built GCCXML tool. It parses C++-files and generates XML. But it would be great to parse C++ XML and then get C++ from XML to be sure that GCCXML utility parses right. Also It would be interesting to change generated XML files and get the corresponding C++ code from changed XML. Although, XML-files can be parsed and necessary information from them can be used in my program. If it is impossible with help of GCCXML, or in another trivial way, just say it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since types are a big complex argument, I would suggest to use [GCCXML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html). It's a frontend that produces an abstract syntax tree from concrete source. I used it to generate interfaces Prolog/OpenGL. If you want to put it to good use you'll need a good XML reader (SWI-Prolog it's really good at this).

*edit*

the following micro file x.c

```
typedef struct A {
  int X, Y;
} T;

T v[100];
```

processed with

```
gccxml -fxml=x.xml x.c
```

produces in x.xml (among many others) the following xml statement

```
...
<Variable id="_3" name="v" type="_141" context="_1" location="f0:5" file="f0" line="5"/>
...
<Struct id="_139" name="A" context="_1" mangled="1A" demangled="A" location="f0:1" file="f0" line="1" artificial="1" size="64" align="32" members="_160 _161 _162 _163 _164 _165 " bases=""/>
<Typedef id="_140" name="T" type="_139" context="_1" location="f0:3" file="f0" line="3"/>
<ArrayType id="_141" min="0" max="99u" type="_140" size="6400" align="32"/>
...
<Field id="_160" name="X" type="_147" offset="0" context="_139" access="public" location="f0:2" file="f0" line="2"/>
<Field id="_161" name="Y" type="_147" offset="32" context="_139" access="public" location="f0:2" file="f0" line="2"/>
<Destructor id="_162" name="A" artificial="1" throw="" context="_139" access="public" mangled="_ZN1AD1Ev *INTERNAL* " demangled="A::~A()" location="f0:1" file="f0" line="1" endline="1" inline="1">
</Destructor>
```

You can see that following the type="..." symbol chain you can reconstruct the type assigned to typedef.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Do you mean to replace my parser with GCCXML? 
I'd like to use my parser. :) Is there some fast and easy way to just unveal typedefs with GCCXML? Could you explain what should I do to replace typedefs with help of GCCXML, please?

Comment: GCCXML produces an XML representation of the interface, where complex types are 'destructured' up to elementary types, stored by name. Then you could use the output of GCCXML as symbol table lookup. It's nevertheless rather complex, because types are *nested* structures. I'll try to build a mini sample...

Comment: It's a very interesting solution. :)
But I still have some questions. How does it possible to get C/C++ program from xml?
Sorry, but I am newbie in XML parsing. Are there effective libraries to perform "following the type="" " ... ? :)
May be, it is enough to implement a simple bash script to perform such replacement?

Comment: I think that the easier way to read XML depends on what language you are using and are acquainted: if it's C++, there is plenty of XML parsers, for instance I used some time ago [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/). To inspect the structure manually and learn about the representation any decent text editor will do, or use Firefox that can display folding.

Comment: Could you explain, how to transform XML-file back to C/C++?

Comment: I don't see the point. XML should be read in memory and handled as a symbol table. You surely will have one in your actual code, extend what you have with the help of (for instance) RapidXML...

Comment: Of course, it is possible to handle the XML within my program. But it's just interesting, is there way to transform XML to C++? :)

Also, I've made some experiments:
typedef int& INT; 

was transformed to:
{
  <ReferenceType id="_125" type="_151" size="32" align="32"/>
  <Typedef id="_126" name="INT" type="_125" context="_1" location="f1:8" file="f1" line="8"/>
}

So, perhaps it isn't so easy to unveal the initial type... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for respond! Your tips were very useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

For resolving macros you can use cpp, the gcc preprocessor, it prints to stdout the preprocessed code.
Unfortunately for you typedef are not macros, so you would need to handle them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're jumping the gun on translation phases. Typedef substitution seems easy in comparison to comment substitution. Does your program recognise the following as comments, yet? If not, then I'd suggest going back to translation phases 1&2 before attempting 3&4.

```
// this is a basic comment
/* this is another basic comment */

// this is a slightly\
   less basic comment
/* this is a slightly
 * less basic comment */

/??/
*??/
c??/
o??/
m??/
m??/
e??/
n??/
t??/
*??/
/
```

Answer (score -1):

Parsing C++ is very hard, requiring a recursive descent parser. I suggest you use GCCXML as proposed by @CapelliC, or as a better maintained alternative, use [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html). There even exist Python bindings which make it's use so much simpler.

Comment: AFAIK C++ (and C also) cannot be parsed with a recursive parser (that accounts for the *simpler* parsing technology available), and its grammar isn't neither context free...

Comment: C++ does not require a recursive descent parser.  It can be parsed by a variety of means with some hackery in some cases (GCC famously used to parse with LALR and hacks), with no hackery in others.  Our C++ front end uses GLR parsing and parses ANSI C++11, GCC and MS 2012 dialects just fine, with no hackery.   It *does* require a huge amount of attention to detail, and then you get to do name and type resolution, which is far harder than parsing.

Comment: I stand corrected ;-) But the main point was that in order to get it right, an enormous effort is required.